# Are there any English words starting with a silent vowel requiring "a" before it (not "an")?

Tags: silent-letters, consonants

Title says it all. We all know there are instances of the other way around, such as "an hour," but I'm curious if any exist. I couldn't think of any.

Like "a orange" if "orange" used a silent "o" and was actually pronounced "range".

Comment: How is "an hour" considered to be "the other way around"?

Comment: @Laurel I was an idiot and rushed through this to leave for work. :S I corrected the original question.

Comment: Looks like title didn't say it all after all, lmao.

Comment: Not exactly starting with a silent vowel but words like _university_, _unicorn_, _universe_, _unison_ takes an "a" because they have the /ju:/ sound at the beginning. They are generally formed with _uni-_ combining form. _Aisle_ is close also but no cigar. Probably there aren't any.

Comment: "Silent" vowel letters, the most prominent being "e" are normally found at the end of words, (*hate, pole, decide*) sometimes in the middle ( the 2nd "e" in *vegetables*, and the "i" in *business*). Is this Q just a curiosity thing? What inspired you to ask? I'm tempted to cast the 3rd and final vote for closure because it seems you not given much thought to this Q and you have not explained the scope either.

Comment: The word  *opossum* is pronounced with a silent "o" more often than not in the U.S., but we've started spelling it *'possum* or *possum*. See [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possum%2C+opossum%2C+%27possum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3).

Comment: @PeterShor That's useful. I believe this question to be clear and your comment would be a useful answer -- please add it! I think that seeing "a opossum" in print would be ... *disconcerting,* though.

Comment: There are several words with an initial vowel which is often dropped, e.g. *around* (*'round*), *about* (*'bout*), *and* (*'n'*), although few of these are nouns (which the question seems to want). [aesthetic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aesthetic) arguably starts with a silent *a* (evidently the Americans agreed and removed it) but has an *e* following so it doesn't meet the full requirement.

Answer (score 4):

In American English, the word *opossum* is pronounced with a silent "o" more often than not. However, Americans have started spelling it *'possum* or *possum*. See this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possum%2C+opossum%2C+%27possum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3).

So rather than write "a opossum", we write "a possum" or "a 'possum". [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/possum-vs-opossum-difference-pronunciation#:%7E:text=Your%20friendly%20Merriam%2DWebster%20dictionary,the%20creatures%20of%20both%20areas.), discussing the pronunciation, writes

> To make things even more confusing, some people say you should spell it opossum but pronounce it without that first syllable; our pronunciation guidance at the entry for opossum recognizes this by putting that first syllable in parentheses: (ə-)ˈpä-səm.

However, very few people write *a opossum* (see [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+opossum%2Ca+opossum%2Ca+possum%2Can+possum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)), so presumably the people who think you should spell it "opossum" but pronounce it *possum* write it "an opossum" and pronounce it *a possum*. As Andrew Leach writes in the comments: "seeing 'a opossum' in print would be ... *disconcerting*."

Comment: There is also an animal called a [_possum (Phalangeriformes)_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalangeriformes) and it is different from an [_opossum (Didelphimorphia)_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opossum). This makes the situation even more complicated. Although, possums live in Australia and in some islands around, far from North America; and a lay person in USA and Canada will understand and use _possum_ as _opossum_. And _OED_ even lists _opossum_ for both animals! * *facepalm* *

Comment: Most of us Americans have forgotten that there's a silent O in _possum_ and never use it. Plus we don't write about them often, so spelling is irrelevant. And possums in Oz are much cuter.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such words in British English.

The closest English comes is with Latinate words starting *iu-* which in Latin are pronounced /ju:/, so you would have "a iubilus" for example (that's a term from plainchant).

The only words contained in OED which start *iu-* are the obsolete adjective *iulan*, and nouns *iulidan* and *iulus,* all derived ultimately from Greek ἴουλος or *down; catkin.*

These are all pronounced with a long initial *i,* /ʌɪˈjuːləs/ and consequently require the *an* form of the article.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "aisle" meets the technical criteria, but still has a vocalized vowel sound at the very beginning.

Comment: You write "a aisle"?